# Difference between createState() and return StateObject() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the difference between `_StateObjectName createState() => _StateObjectName();` and `return _StateObjectName();` apart from the way written? Does it have any difference in functionality or do they do the same thing?

Comment: These are the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first syntax is an "arrow" function (since the => looks like an arrow, very creative I know). It's just a shorthand way of writing a function that has only one line. Here is what the arrow function would look like using the normal return syntax:

```
_StateObjectName createState() {
    return _StateObjectName();
}
```

Long story short, they mean the same thing but the arrow function can be a good way to condense cluttered code.